# Finding the smallest sum above the minimum required in a dictionary in python

Tags: python, dictionary

First I feel the need to explain the motivation for this question. Lately, I have been playing a game on my cell phone whose main aim is to capture 270 votes in the election and become POTUS. In order to win the backing of a certain category, you have to win the majority of those states' assigned weight in dollars.

So I was concerned with the minimum amount of money needed to capture the category where those states fall. This made dictionaries an excellent choice for the problem. Below is a dictionary with state initials as keys and their weight in dollars.

```
states_dict = { 'CA': 200, 'TX':200, 'NY': 150, 'FL': 100, 'IL': 50, 'AR':24, 'CO': 18, 'NM': 15, 'NV': 17.5 , 'NJ': 42.5}
```

In the beginning, one has to find the sum of the dictionary entries and divide it by 2. If a partial sum is smaller than the half-sum we have to keep adding and as soon as it passes or hits the half-sum we have to stop and compare it to a previous minimum. If it's smaller we have to replace the current minimum with the newly-found minimum.

I am new to dictionaries and I only know how to traverse them but yet here I have to calculate every partial sum in the list. Is there a way to calculate the SMALLEST POSSIBLE SUM in this list?

Comment: What are 'partial sum' and 'half sum'?

Comment: @DevanshSoni "the partial sum" refers to every sum possible in the dictionary for example the values of TX+CA, CO+NM  , CO+NM+TX+AR etc. In a nutshell, every possible sum involving the values of the keys present in the dict

Comment: @DevanshSoni the half-sum is simply the sum divided by 2 . If the sum of the states you've gathered is bigger than half-sum you win the backing of that group

Comment: can you expain your expected output with an example

Comment: @deadshot sure. Suppose we have the following dict { 'CA':200,'TX':200,'NY':150,'FL':100,'IL':50}. The sum is 700 , therefore the half sum is 350. The program (or function) has to print(or return) a string with the states whose added weights equal 350. In this case 'CA+NY', there is more than 1 combination but in this case it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so at first i thought i could simplyjust sort the values in ascending order then add them up until i got a value that is more than the required minimum, however i realised that you could even use the largest value and add it to the lowest value and get a value that is lower than the one you get when you add the sorted values right ?

so what that meant for me was that for this code to work if you have 10 values, you need to get the different combinations, that is all the ways that this values could be selected so that you can get the different sums of 9 different numbers,8 numbers,  7 numbers......up to 2 numbers, or 1 number anyways

so this code works by getting the different combinations like that for 9 numbers up to 1 number...10 numbers wasn't useful because if you have only 10 numbers no matter how you select them you'll still have the same sum for the numbers

in the code i have added comments to show exactly where these steps are and how i did them

```
    import itertools
    # itertools is used to generate all possible combinations for the values, its there automatically 
    # you don't need to download it
    states_dict = { 'CA': 200, 'TX':200, 'NY': 150, 'FL': 100, 'IL': 50, 'AR':24, 'CO': 18, 'NM': 15, 'NV': 17.5 , 'NJ': 42.5}
    
    #calculating the minimum by dividing total by 2
    #getting the sum of all the values in the dictionary
    total = sum(states_dict.values())
   
    #dividing the sum by 2 to get the minimum
    minimum = total/2

    #displaying the minimum
    print("The minimum value is: {}".format(minimum))
    #Output: The minimum value is: 408.5
    
    # storing the values only in a list, so that its easier to work with them
    values = list(states_dict.values())

    #empty list that will store all the combinations from 9 numbers to 1 number
    all_combinations = []
    
    #empty list that will store all the sums of the different combination, the sum of each combination is stored as a different element
    all_sums = []
    
    #generates a list of all possible combinations
    #r is number of numbers that is involved in the combination
    #when r is 5 it will get all the ways that five different numbers from the list of 10 numbers can be selected
    # the length here is 10, so the combinations will only reach 9 numbers
    for r in range(len(values)):
        #here is where i used itertools to generate the combinations for me (nCr)
        combinations_object = itertools.combinations(values, r) #takes iterable(values) and r(number of numbers)

       #convert the itertools object to a list, so that we can add it to the bigger list, also so that we can get the sum of the elements easily kater
        combinations_list = list(combinations_object)

        # adding the new combination to the bigger list, which makes a 2d array
        all_combinations += combinations_list
        
    #generates a list of the sums of the values in the combinations        
    for objects in all_combinations:
        #the sum function here adds the values in each combination
        sum_object = sum(list(objects))
        #adding the sum into an array which holds the sums of the different combinations
        all_sums.append(sum_object)
     
    
    #sorts the list of sums in ascending order (smallest sum to largest sum)
    all_sums = sorted(all_sums)
    
    #gets lowest sum that is above the minimum
    
    #now that the list of sums is sorted, we just iterate through it so that immediately it gets a sum that is above the minimum value(408.5) it captures it and stores it in a variable (required value)
    for sum_object in all_sums:
        if (sum_object>minimum):
            # store required value once the loop reaches it
            required_value = sum_object
            #display the required value (409.5)
            print("The required value is: {}".format(sum_object),end="\n")
            #break out of the loop because we've got what we wanted and don't need to continue looping
            break
      
    #prints out the combinations whose sum is the required value
    #re-using the list of combinations now that we have the value, we just check whether the sum of the values inside the combination is the same as the required value, and if it is we print it out
    print("\nThe combinations are: ")
    for objects in all_combinations:
        #if the sum of number in combination is same as required value
        if (sum(list(objects)) == required_value):
            #display the items in that combination
            print(objects,end="\n")
            
    #Output
    # The minimum value is: 408.5
    # The required value is: 409.5
    
    # The combinations are: 
    # (17.5, 18, 24, 150, 200)
    # (17.5, 18, 24, 150, 200)
    # (17.5, 18, 24, 50, 100, 200)
    # (17.5, 18, 24, 50, 100, 200)
```

I didn't go on to then display the states that would have this values because i thought it would make the code really long and tedious to read considering that the person who asked only asked for the value

so I hope this is what you were looking for and it helps you

Comment: A code-only answer may help OP immediately, but StackOverflow isn't meant for just OP. SO isn't a website for people to crowdsource their code, and a code-only answer encourages such behavior. A good answer includes an explanation of how/why this code fixes the problem. Oh, and please let's keep the asking for upvotes on Youtube.

Comment: whoaa...sorry bro

Comment: ok lemme edit the code to explain how it works...i'm just new to stack that's why i didnt do much of the explaining, i don't know how to use the features well